# Does C's strtok function support regex?

Tags: c

Let's say I have to parse some phone numbers that can have different delimiters.

Example: 01/555555 01/555-5555

Can I use `strtok()` in c and give a regex as a delimiter parameter that would include all the different possible delimiters?

Comment: What does [available documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) say?

Comment: `man strtok` is pretty comprehensive..

Comment: @DevSolar I am sorry, from the name ... But I just saw the */c/* in the url.

Comment: I don't like them since I've found there some nasty errors..

Comment: @DevSolar It's pretty much personal, the errors were a while ago, but the opinion remains :)

Comment: @DevSolar: then try out www.die.net they are actually most satisfying for me ;)

Comment: @DevSolar I was using tutorialspoint and they were not clear on the point.

Comment: @Zaibis: Yes, those are exactly the kind of `man` pages I was talking about. They tell you what POSIX specifies, not what ISO/IEC 9899:2011 specifies. For some of us, that's a *real* difference.

Comment: @DevSolar POSIX spec is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html , the man pages are the Linux spec (I agree that they may be more practical in some situations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not support *regex*. Read the documentation before asking. On the other hand, that's precisely how it works so again [Read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), i.e. You give it all the possible delimiters.

Check it here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char example[] = "exa$mple@str#ing";
    char *token;
    char *pointer;
    pointer = example;
    token = strtok(pointer, "@#$");
    if (token == NULL)
        return -1;
    do
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", token);
        pointer = NULL;
    } while ((token = strtok(NULL, "@#$")) != NULL);

}
```

Comment: You can even change the delimiters during parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to iharob's answer, `sscanf` may sometimes be an alternative to `strtok`. Here's an illustration with the given example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "01/555555 01/555-5555";
    int a, b, c, d, e;

    int ret = sscanf(s, "%02d/%d %02d/%d-%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    if (ret != 5) {
        printf("The string is in bad format.\n");
    } else {
        printf("%02d/%d %02d/%d-%d\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Like `strtok`, it doesn't support regex but it enables to extract the data within one single line. It works exactly like scanf but it reads from a given string instead of reading from the standard input.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Comment: if you claim sscanf is capable of supporting regex(at least thats what op asked for) Then give an explanation of how your code does this. As I can't actually see how this implements any kind of regex support. Thats why I downvoted.

Comment: Ok I understand. My answer looks like I claimed that sscanf supports regex, whereas it was a complement to the first answer, but that was not clear. However, my code clearly shows that I don't claim that sscanf supports regex, because there's no regex at all in the code. I will edit my answer according to your remarks. Thanks.